# Window batch file error: ( was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file

Here is my run.bat file:

```
set var1 = %1
IF %var1%=="Yes" (
    Echo deleting filename.txt
 ) ELSE ( 
    Echo The file was not found.
 )
```

I am running it like: run.bat -h and i am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test>run.bat -h

C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test>set var1 = -h
( was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\admin\Desktop\test>IF =="Yes" (
```

Comment: firstly, get rid of the spaces in set. `set var1=%1` Secondly, did you pass a value? lastly, why are you comparing if something == "something" you need to double quote both.

Comment: There's no need for the `Set` command in this context, so you could instead use `If /I "%~1"=="-h" (`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ran it without %1 argument.

In command line run:

```
run.bat something
```

and not just

```
run.bat
```

also to avoid this, you have to use quotes for %var1% in order to make `IF` work properly:

```
set "var1=%1"
IF "%var1%"=="Yes" (
    Echo deleting filename.txt
 ) ELSE ( 
    Echo The file was not found.
 )
```

And then you can run it without arguments, and it will not complain.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, you need a value passed to the script to assign it so `%1` can use it. Also double quotes around your variable sets and it is better to check if you passed a value or not:

```
@echo off
set "var1=%1"
if not defined var1 echo you did not pass a value. usage "batch.cmd parameter" & pause & exit
if /I "%var1%"=="Yes" (
   echo deleting filename.txt
 ) else ( 
   echo The file was not found.
)
```